# Collasping toolbar leave space at the bottom of layout android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-support-design

`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:textColor="@color/hedarcolor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hederimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/frow_logo"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill">


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
```

`I am animating toolbar on scroll using`Recycleview` in Android, it leave space marked in the image at the bottom of my layout.
tried

1. `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to Appbarlayout, collapsing toolbar and Cordinatelayout.
2. `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` befor setcontentview

Both the options did not work.
Help me out to get rid of this problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you get answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
CoordinatorLayout= (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.cl_my_account);
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
CoordinatorLayout.setMinimumHeight(display.getHeight());
```